# How often do a LTE eNodeB scheduler schedule?

Tags: digital-communications, communication-standard, lte

Scheduler schedules the resource for each UE. How often do a LTE eNodeB scheduler schedule? Is the time between each scheduling fixed?
 any idea/reference will be great help on this regard. Thanks.

Comment: It depends what resources are scheduled for. For CQI, SRS, ... i.e. uplink aided-info, the scheduling pattern are quasi-static can be found in specs. For data, it depends on UE's request (BSR), application QoS, subcriber priviliedge, ... almost of this are implemented in Policy and Charging Rules Function (PCRF) of the core network. At eNB level, the scheduling rate depends on a lot of thing such as eNB load, UE connection quality, ... and the algorithm of scheduler are equimenter-specific.